# How to linkedin application in full profile permissions add

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have get LinkedIn Full profile experience, education, skills, and recommendations.

But my LinkedIn application in not `r_fullprofile` permission display.

so how to display `r_fullprofile` in my application. please some help me...

LinkedIn application in not show scope:- `'r_fullprofile','r_network','r_contactinfo'`.

LinkedIn application in only show scope:- `'r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress','rw_company_admin','w_share'`.

**My code example:-**

```
$api_key = "apikey";
$api_secret = "api_secret";
$callback_url = "";
//$scope = array('r_basicprofile','r_fullprofile','r_emailaddress','r_network','r_contactinfo');
$scope = array('r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress');


$config = array('api_key' => $api_key, 'api_secret' => $api_secret , 'callback_url' => $callback_url);
$connection = new LinkedIn($config);

if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
    $code = $_REQUEST['code'];
    $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($code);
    $connection->setAccessToken($access_token);

     $user = $connection->get("people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline,industry,summary,positions,picture-url,skills,educations,languages,twitter-accounts,location:(name,country:(code),postal-code),recommendations-received:(recommendation-text,recommender:(first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,headline,picture-url)))");

    $_SESSION['User_Get_Full_Info'] = $user;


    header('Location: index.php');

}
else{

    if (isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {
        header('Location: index.php?error_code=1');
    }
    else{
        $authUrl = $connection->getLoginUrl($scope);
        header("Location: $authUrl");
    }
}
```

Comment: please post some code of what you have tried so far, where are you getting those variables from and what is the expected result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733044/unable-to-get-entire-information-from-linkedin-api