# Unable to get entire information from linkedIn api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, linkedin-api

I have tried this

**Html:**

```
<a id="li_ui_li_gen_1432549871566_0-link" class="" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="onLinkedInLoad();" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
```

**JS code:**

```
function onLinkedInLoad(logintype) {

  IN.User.authorize(function(){
          callback();
  });      

}
function callback(){
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", OnLinkedInAuth);
        OnLinkedInAuth();
}
function OnLinkedInAuth(){     

    IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields("firstName", "lastName", "industry", "location:(name)", "picture-url", "headline", "summary", "num-connections", "public-profile-url", "distance", "positions", "email-address", "educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)","languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name))","skills:(id,skill:(name))", "date-of-birth")
.result(ShowProfileData)
.error(displayProfilesErrors);    
}

function ShowProfileData(profiles) {
    console.log(profiles); return false;

    //its gives me json responce 
    /*   {
        "_total": 1,
        "values": [{
          "_key": "~",
          "distance": 0,
          "emailAddress": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
          "firstName": "xxxx",
          "headline": "xxxxx",
          "industry": "Information Technology and Services",
          "lastName": "xxx",
          "location": {"name": "xxx Area, India"},
          "numConnections": 117,
          "positions": {
            "_total": 1,
            "values": [{
              "company": {
                "id": xxxxx,
                "industry": "E-Learning",
                "name": "xxxx",
                "size": "501-1000 employees",
                "type": "Privately Held"
              },
              "id": 485779823,
              "isCurrent": true,
              "startDate": {
                "month": 2,
                "year": 2013
              },
              "title": "xxxxx"
            }]
          },
          "publicProfileUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxxx/xx/xx/xx"
        }]
      } */      
}
function displayProfilesErrors(error) {
    profilesDiv = document.getElementById("profiles");
    profilesDiv.innerHTML = error.message;
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? What's your question?

Comment: @Mariano .. I unable to get educations,language,skill fields from api

Comment: .fields("firstName", "lastName", "industry", "location:(name)", "picture-url", "headline", "summary", "num-connections", "public-profile-url", "distance", "positions", "email-address", "educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)","languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name))","skills:(id,skill:(name))", "date-of-birth") 
getting few of them

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that some queried fields (e.g. languages, skills, education fields) require that your application have been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn program.

See: [Profile field descriptions](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) page which lists fields that require an additional API (i.e. 'Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers' title), and see how one can apply for using this API: [Request access to this API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) page.